# How to run WGET from ASP.NET MVC class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, wget, orchardcms-1.7

I am building a site in ASP.NET MVC Orchard CMS 1.7, and my client is asking for a peculiar functionality.

I need to create and maintain a folder where all the physical files of the site would be stored, static HTML with directories mirroring URLs. Please don't ask me why but this is a requirement.

The pages would be generated once automatically, then should be generated manually on demand and each time the content changes in CMS, the particular HTML page would regenerate.

the page generation in database is not a problem for me. I have reached to the point where I used Workflow to reach the point of page publish or update. But after that I am stuck.

1. I am confused about what would be a viable solution to get the pages. wget (for windows), crul or something native to ASP.NET
2. How to implement it so that the command line script could be called from class.

I have been trying to do wget (windows based) for this but there has been not much luck with  c#'s process class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [csQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) to achieve this. I have been pretty satisfied with the outcome I am getting since it allows me to target the HTML elements as I do my jQuery css targeting.